# Function overloaded by bool and enum type is not differentiated while called using multiple ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, overloading

Got into an interesting problem while tried to call the overloaded function using conditional operator (just to avoid multiple if else condition)

```
class VirtualGpio
{

    typedef enum
    {
      OUTPUT = 0xC7,
      INPUT ,
      DIRINVALID
    }GpioDirection;
    struct pinconfig
    {
      struct pinmap pin;
      GpioPolarity plrty;  
      bool IsPullupCfgValid;
      bool IsTriStCfgValid;
      bool IsInputFilterValid;
      GpioDirection dic; 
      gpiolistner fptr;     // Callback function pointer on event change
    };

};

class factory
{

  public:

    VirtualGpio *GetGpiofactory(VirtualGpio::pinconfig *cfg,VirtualGpio::GpioAccessTyp acc=VirtualGpio::Pin);

  private:

      int setCfgSetting(VirtualGpio::pinmap * const getpin, VirtualGpio::GpioDirection const data);

      int setCfgSetting(VirtualGpio::pinmap * const getpin, bool const data);

};

int factory::setCfgSetting(VirtualGpio::pinmap * const getpin, VirtualGpio::GpioDirection const data)
{

  cout << "It is a Direction overloaded" << endl;

}

int factory::setCfgSetting(VirtualGpio::pinmap * const getpin, bool const data)
{

   cout << "It is a bool overloaded" << endl;

}

VirtualGpio* factory::GetGpiofactory(VirtualGpio::pinconfig *cfg,VirtualGpio::GpioAccessTyp acc)
{

  VirtualGpio * io = new VirtualGpio();

  printf("acc : 0x%X, pin : 0x%x, port : 0x%x\n",acc, cfg->pin.pinno, cfg->pin.portno);

  printf("value of expression : 0x%x\n",((acc == VirtualGpio::Pin)? cfg->dic : ((cfg->dic == VirtualGpio::INPUT)?true :false))); <= this prints the right value

  if(acc == VirtualGpio::Pin)

      setCfgSetting(&cfg->pin,cfg->dic);

  else if(cfg->dic == VirtualGpio::INPUT)

      setCfgSetting(&cfg->pin,true);

  else

      setCfgSetting(&cfg->pin,false);

#if 0
  if(setCfgSetting(&cfg->pin, ((acc == VirtualGpio::Pin)? cfg->dic : ((cfg->dic == VirtualGpio::INPUT)?true :false))) == ERROR)
   {

      printf("Error Setting the IO configuration for XRA\n");

   }

   else

    printf("Set IO config successfully\n");

#endif

  return io;

}
```

The commented part `#if 0` in `GetGpiofactory()` is same as the above
 multiple if-else-if-else block, but if I uncomment the #if0 part to #if
 1, for all the possible inputs only bool version of the overloaded
 function i.e `setCfgSetting(VirtualGpio::pinmap * const getpin, bool
 const data)` is invoked.

below is my main code.

```
main()
{

  static struct VirtualGpio::pinconfig cfg = {

    .pin = {
      .location = VirtualGpio::GPIO_ON_GPIOEXP1_TCI,
      .pinno = 0,
      .portno = -1
    },
    .plrty = VirtualGpio::active_high,
    .IsPullupCfgValid = true,
    .IsTriStCfgValid = true,
    .IsInputFilterValid = true,
    .dic = VirtualGpio::OUTPUT,
    .fptr = NULL
  };

  factory fac;

  fac.GetGpiofactory(&cfg);

}
```

Surprised, the overloaded function works well if I don't use the ternary operator instead use multiple if-else if-else blocks. curious to understand the reason.

Comment: We can live with bad English (my French is dreadful after all), but your lack of attention to formatting is reprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the ternary operator always evaluates to a single type. You can't "return" different types with this operator.

When the compiler encounters such an expression he tries to figure out whether he can reduce the whole thing to one type. If that's not possible you get a compile error.

In your case there is a valid option using `bool` as a type. Because `cfg->dic` is an `enum` type which is implicitly convertible to `bool`. If you would use and `enum class` your code would not compile anymore showing you what your actual problem is ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fbf7ec0769de6f8)).

Also I don't really see what the advantage of this kind of code is. In my opinion it makes the code much harder to read. You could reduce your `ifs` to just one, if you're concerned about too many of them:

```
if(acc == VirtualGpio::Pin)
  setCfgSetting(&cfg->pin,cfg->dic);
else
  setCfgSetting(&cfg->pin, cfg->dic == VirtualGpio::INPUT);
```

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian, probably I might need more understanding, the expression, 
setCfgSetting(&cfg->pin, ((acc == VirtualGpio::Pin)? cfg->dic : ((cfg->dic == VirtualGpio::INPUT)?true :false))) == ERROR)  finally turns out to either "1' or "0" eventhough the value of cfg->dic = "0xC7",  are you saying after type cast will the enum value 0xC7 as a bool
 will end up in "1" or "0"?. moreover I am assuming the whole expression is evaluating only to the righthand side of the first ternary operator even 
 if I force to make the left handside of the first conditional operator to true